# Get time since boot in FreeRTOS

Tags: freertos

I'm using http://www.freertos.org/ for an application, but I can't find how to get the system time since boot. I can create a task and keep updating a counter, but I don't think it will be a good thing since the scheduler might schedule down my task (and putting a higher priority might hang my 'real' work tasks).

So, I want to know what might be the best solution to get how many ms elapsed since the system boot up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think `xTaskGetTickCount()` does what you want: http://www.freertos.org/a00021.html#xTaskGetTickCount

Comment: What's wrong with using the time() or clock() from time.h?  (I'm not arguing, but asking...)  In my generated code, xTaskGetTickCount() always returns 0.  Does that mean I missed a setting when running STM32CubeMX?

Comment: You may need to enable this function first in the config file to get a valid value out of this.

Comment: Take care as the tick count will overflow.

Answer (score 1):

`xTaskGetTickCount()` is common way, but if you need to have the exact time since boot (for example, uptime, as Tick Counter is unsigned 32-bit integer, thus its overflow is possible), please consider using RTC time, memorizing the start point and return the diff between RTC actual time and start point

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend using `clock()` from time.h, in conjunction with `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to keep things as portable as possible.

(credit Paul Williams' comment above)

Comment: You need to make sure that `clock()` returns what you expect on the system in question.  In principle, `clock()` returns approximate CPU time used by the current process; system time since boot is in general something entirely different.